# Can a JS string variable be used in Twig?

Tags: javascript, guest-entries

I've came to the situation where I need to use JS variable string and use it in Twig's variable.

The plan is built on the [Guest entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) and Ajax form submission. On successful Ajax form submission I'm calling for entry's keys (especially `id` key) and using these keys to set a cookie names. Those cookie names should be used on next page to get into the entry that just got submitted. Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Twig is rendered server side before passed to a browser for JS execution I found out that it can't be done except [FOSsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) which allows you to expose your routing in your JavaScript code. I don't know if that would be a great idea.

Anyway. I found workaround solution that seems to be working for me.

**Here is the Ajax post action with simple window redirection.**

```
// Send it to the server
$.post('/', data, function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

  if (response.success) {

    // Request for entry ID key string to be used in HTTP redirect link
    var entryId = response.id

    // HTTP redirect
    window.location.replace("{{ siteUrl }}" + entryId + "/someUri");

    } else {
    // response.error
  }

});
```

Don't forget Craft's routing!